# How to split a string using any word from a list of word

Tags: python-3.x

How to split a string using any word from a list of word

I have a list of string 
`l = ['IV', 'IX', 'XL', 'XC', 'CD', 'CM']`

I need to split for example 'XCVI' based on this list like 
`'XC-V-I'`

Comment: Why are `V` and `I` parsed as separate characters? Didn't you want to split based on _two_ adjacent characters? The combination `XC` in in the list, but there's no `VI`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one solution but I'm not sure if it's the best way to do that:

```
def split(s, l):
    tokens = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(s):
        if s[i:i+2] in l:
            tokens.append(s[i:i+2])
            i += 2
        else:
            tokens.append(s[i])
            i += 1
    return '-'.join(tokens)
```

where `s` is the input string such as `"XCVI"`.

Result:

```
l = ['IV', 'IX', 'XL', 'XC', 'CD', 'CM']

>>> split('XCVI', l)
XC-V-I
>>> split('IXC', l)
IX-C
>>> split('IXXC', l)
IX-XC
```